# apache httpd ACLs not working

Tags: acl, apache-httpd

What is the issue with the rule below

```
<Directory /data/share/web/marketing/jacaranda>
 #AllowOverride All
    <Files "wp-login.php">
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 10.25.100.0/24 10.25.110.0/24
    </Files>
 </Directory>
```

I want to deny access to `wp-login.php` from all except the above two networks . But this is not working ..what I am missing here

Comment: which error you have? there is a problem with the lans, 10.25.100.10/24 is an error... I think is sufficient 10.25.100.0/24

Comment: Sorry , it was typo..just corrected it..should have been 10.25.110.0/24

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved for now . The rules were correct . Was accessing `wp-login.php`  by setting `http_proxy` in the `browser` which was not added in the ACL list . After adding the  proxy network in the ACL list , it started working fine . I was able to access `wp-login.php` only from allowed networks in ACLs